# How can I find the timezone of a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, timezone

Is there an easy way to find the `timezone` for `datetime` dataype of `SQL Server` database?

Answer (score 34):

You can use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`.  This will tell you the offset from GMT at the end.

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
```

> 2016-06-21 08:36:54.9753055 **-04:00**

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone
```

Comment: That's the timezone of the Windows server, is it not? And not the timezone of the database.